# Create a dialog in google chat

Tags: api, bots, chatbot, google-hangouts, google-chat

I have followed the documentation provided by google https://developers.google.com/chat/how-tos/bot-dialogs but cannot figure out how to respond correctly to the "REQUEST_DIALOG" event. Here is what I did so far:

I created a new slash command with "opens a dialog"
[image]

This results in an request dialog event as expected:

```
  "type": "MESSAGE",
  "eventTime": "2021-07-27T11:34:55.036447Z",
  "message": {
    "name": "***",
    "sender": {
      "name": "***",
      "displayName": "***",
      "avatarUrl": "***",
      "email": "***",
      "type": "HUMAN",
      "domainId": "***"
    },
    ..."slashCommand": {
      "commandId": "17"
    },
    "lastUpdateTime": "2021-07-27T11:34:55.036447Z"
  },
  .."configCompleteRedirectUrl": "https://chat.google.com/api/bot_config_complete?token\u003dAAJCfVWmnk9F9-p3tLQJcUN0lhskjka74V3SMYvZ5dQ_l4Ft1VkCG7JDybLxvLEc7WRwK05c768H6UO3d_EPzehsb2hnt1faOJsgSI6xUIZshjA2PNj1iWCyzp5JmtJtfDOzbmPjlUR7lW2bcOT5",
  "isDialogEvent": true,
  "dialogEventType": "REQUEST_DIALOG"
}
```

But I cannot figure out how to respond properly.  A card, the ok response or follow-up dialog (as in the example) do not seem to work.

Can someone please provide a simple example that should work ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got it working. Here is the response that can be used to generate a simple dialog in google chat.

```
{
  "action_response": {
    "dialog_action": {
      "dialog": {
        "body": {
          "sections": [
            {
              "widgets": [
                {
                  "textInput": {
                    "label": "Text input",
                    "type": "SINGLE_LINE",
                    "name": "fieldName"
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    "type": "DIALOG"
  }
}
```

It will look something like this:

[image]

The following page helped me to get it right.
https://developers.googleblog.com/2021/06/add-dialogs-and-slash-commands-to-your-google-workspace-chat-bots.html